# Problemas para usar dropdaown en bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo este formulario, al seleccionar alguna opción del `dropdown`, este despliega los formularios correctamente la primera vez, pero si yo vuelvo a seleccionar una opción que haya desplegado anteriormente, ya no despliega nada, básicamente cada opción solo se despliega una vez necesito ayuda, no se que estoy haciendo mal o porque solo puedo mostrar solo una vez cada formulario, es urgente!!!!

```
 <div class="container my-4 text-light" id="contenerdor" style="background-color:#C40053">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-light" role="tablist">



          <li class="dropdown open">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle text-light px-3" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Alumnos
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="text-dark px-3"  href="#veralumnos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mostrar alumnos</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-dark px-3"  href="#registraralumno" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Registrar alumno</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class="dropdown open">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle text-light px-3" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profesores
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="text-dark px-3"  href="#verprofesores" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mostrar profesores</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-dark px-3"  href="#registrarprofesor" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Registrar profesor</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>



          <li><a class="text-light px-3" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Grupos</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div class="tab-content">


          <div id="registraralumno" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Registrar un nuevo alumno</h3>

            <div class="container my-5 w-75 text-light">


             <!--   <form action="registraralumno.php" method="POST" id="formalumno"class="form"> -->

                        <label for="nombre" class="sr-only">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombreAl" id="nombreAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                        <label for="apep" class="sr-only">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apepAl" id="apepAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" required>
                        <label for="apem" class="sr-only">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apemAl" id="apemAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Apellido Materno" required>
                        <label for="telefono" class="sr-only">Telefono</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefonoAl" id="telefonoAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Telefono" required>
                        <label for="direccion" class="sr-only">Direccion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="direccionAl" id="direccionAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Direccion" required>
                        <label for="tutor" class="sr-only">Contacto del tutor</label>
                        <input type="text" name="tutorAl" id="tutorAl" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Telefono del tutor" required>

                      <!-- <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">  -->

                        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="validar('1')">Registrar</button>


               <!-- </form> -->

          </div>

        </div>



        <div id="registrarprofesor" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Registrar un nuevo profesor</h3>

            <div class="container my-5 w-75 text-light field-wrap">


                <form action="registrarprofe.php" method="POST" id="formprofe"class="form">

                        <label for="nombre" class="sr-only">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                        <label for="apep" class="sr-only">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apep" class="form-control my-3" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" required>
                        <label for="apem" class="sr-only">Apellido Materno</label>


                        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary button-block mb-3">


                </form>

          </div>

        </div>


          <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Profesores</h3>
            <h1 class="h3 mt-5 font-weight-normal">Inicia sesión</h1>

                        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> 
          </div>


          <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Grupos</h3>
            <p>Nada alv.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="veralumnos" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Ver los alumnos</h3>

        <table class="table table-striped table-dark mb-5" id="tablaAl">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
              <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
              <th scope="col">Direccion</th>
              <th scope="col">Telefono del tutor</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="tbody-dark">

        </tbody>

        </table>

          </div>
          <div id="verprofesores" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Ver los profesores</h3>
            <p>Pos aqui se ven.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="nada" class="tab-pane fade">

            <p>Nada</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedo observar es que estas utilizando dos procedimientos distintos, me explico, colocas role="tab" data-toggle="tab" en cada etiqueta "" para mostrar los formularios, nunca se me hubiera ocurrido, combinar atributos data de esa manera, pero lo que te recomiendo es que trabajes con jquery para mostrar y ocultar elementos.

te pogo un ejemplo:

```js
$("#BtnAddCliente").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // alert("es una alerta");
   AbrirFormAdd();
 });

    function AbrirFormAdd()
 {
  $("#FormAlumno")[0].reset();/*Limpiar Formulario*/
        $("#FormAlumno").slideToggle("slow");/*MOSTRAR FORM*/
 }
```

Espero que te sirva!